# Font-Awesome fa-circle with two colors?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a half circle like onto my page but I'm struggling a bit using fa fa-adjust

```
<i class="fa fa-adjust" style="color: green"></i>
```

At this point I cant change the left side of the circle.  Can a CSS wizard please help me so I can configure the two colors of the circle?  I want the right side to be green and the left to be gray.

Below is the circle I want(ideally), WITH the same CSS settings as the "fa-circle".  I was hoping I could copy the fa-circle CSS and then create some  CSS tweaks.  When I navigated to the fontawesome.css file there were basically codes for each type and thus I couldn't make any mods.

Any help would be great.  Thanks guys!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCVct.jpg

[image]

Comment: Use `:after` to create the affect. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/8gzzrtwv/

Comment: fonts can only be one color

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a CSS gradient:

https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/n5kjjvx9/

```css
.fa-adjust, .no-font-needed {
    color: transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #868789 0%, #868789 50%, #008000 50%, #008000 100%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-adjust"></i>

<p>Although, you do not need Font Awesome to do this:</p>
<div class="no-font-needed"></div>
```

To be totally honest though, there is no need to use Font Awesome to accomplish this, as you can see, I do the same thing with a plain old `<div>` in my example.

Comment: This is basically perfect except I am just having a hard time resizing it down to about 12-15px.  It borks out when I change the width/height.

Comment: @Spets looks OK here at `14px`: https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/402p7sf1/. Perhaps you could let me know what you mean by 'borks out'?

Comment: I got this to work with the above css.  thanks man.  I need to get better at the background linear-gradient.

Answer (score 3):

```
.badge {
    color: #FFF;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to left, green, green 50%, #777777 50%);
    border-radius: 100%;
}

<i class="badge fa fa-adjust" ></i>
```

use a gradient background

http://jsfiddle.net/ddpxug88/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve this with font-awesome.  Try using this: http://bryanhadaway.com/how-to-create-circles-with-css/

```
   .left {
       border-top-left-radius:50px; float:left;
       border-bottom-left-radius:50px;
       background:blue;
   }
```

jsfiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/szzse5eg/).

Answer (score 1):

The Font Awesome answer would be to use Font Awesome's font stacking to stack two squares on top of one another offset the the green one and then wrap a white border with a 50% radius around the fonts to mask the squares into a circle.

[Here's a starting point](https://jsfiddle.net/shootermatic/39rfnhsz/)

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x grey"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x green"></i>
</span>

.green { color:green;left:50%;}
.grey { color:grey;}
```

EDIT;

Actually fa-adjust is the icon I was looking for (I should read the question properly).

[This is a better example using font-awesome](https://jsfiddle.net/shootermatic/vhugrg08/)

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-adjust fa-stack-2x green"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-adjust fa-rotate-180 fa-stack-2x grey"></i>
</span>

.green { color:green;}
.grey { color:grey;}
```